# How to horizontally center a div-block containing images?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to horizontally center a div-block containing images (playing cards placed there by Javascript), but somehow it doesn't work (images are still left-aligned). Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="dealerarea">
    <div id="dealercards">
    <!--Images by Javascript-->
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#dealerarea{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:96px;
top:15px;
}
#dealercards{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

What i'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Edit: I can't give a fixed "width" to inner div, because it changes every time (depending on the number of card images).

Comment: What happens if you give dealerarea a fixed width, rather than a % ?

Comment: DiMono, it's still the same with fixed width. Jason, i read that post, but unlike that case my inner div has different width every time (depending on the number of card images) and i didn't find a IE 6 & 7 suitable solution for such a case there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your `#dealercards` a `width` and `margin:0 auto` ;

```
#dealercards
{
display: block;
margin:0 auto;width:200px;
}
```

### [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/SdeMV/)

Comment: Thanks, but i can't give a fixed width to inner div (it contains different number on card images every time).

Comment: @user2721820 you can't use margin:0 auto; to center unless the element has a width. So your going to have to find out a way to.

Comment: #dealerarea{ display:flex; align-items:center;}